# Regex is not working for particular string

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have to find these string using regex:-

```
(APP12345-85)
(APP12345XDP-85) 
(APP12345X-85) 
(APP12345-85)  - not working for this one
(APP12345) - not working for this one
```

the original text is like this 
`.......some text 123 (APP12345-85) some text...............`

My code is:-

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(APP|REG)[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{5}-[0-9]{2}", caseIgnore);

MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(@evalString);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
//code
}
```

Any help will be  appreciated.

Comment: (APP|REG)\d{5}([A-Z]{1,5})?(-\d{2})?

Comment: Isn't your first working one the same as the first non-working one?

Comment: I fail to see how that regex would match *any* of the examples. Particularly the `[A-Z]{5}` part.

Comment: Can I recommend you play with https://regex101.com/... it will explain what your expression is doing, and therefore you can work out how to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also match these entries with

```
\b(APP|REG)[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{0,5}(?:-[0-9]{2})?\b
```

Looks like the uppercase letters are optional, so setting to `{0,5}` looks safe.
And this regex does not check the beginning/end of the string/line.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC0fV9/3).

**UPDATE**:

Here is a sample code for the updated example:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\((APP|REG)[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{0,5}(?:-[0-9]{2})?\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches("(APP12345-85)");
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
  //code
}
```

Output of `matches`:

[image] [image]

Comment: Please check the code snippet I added. BTW, I am keeping the capture groups intact, Avinash transforms the first group to a non-capturing one.

Comment: Yes, just tested. Because the `[A-Z]` letters are optional, from 0 to 5 occurrences, and `(?:-[0-9]{2})?` are optional, too due to the `?` quantifier.